# What are the atomicity guarantees of `fs.appendFile()`?

Tags: node.js

The documentation for `fs.appendFile()` is vague with regard to atomicity guarantees.

I am specifically wondering whether it is supposed to be possible for data to be either interleaved or dropped (e.g. due to writes to overlapping areas) if two or more calls to it are made on the same file, without waiting for the callback in between. For example, take this code:

```
fs.writeFileSync('blort.bin', '');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const data = Buffer.alloc(65536, i);
  fs.appendFile('blort.bin', data, () => {});
}
```

Assuming there are no filesystem errors and no other processes writing to the file in question, would Node make the following guarantees after all of the append operations are done?:

- The file is exactly 640k in size.
- The file consists of 10 64k chunks of data, each uniformly containing a single byte value.

I'm also curious if there's any serialization guarantee (though I assume not). That is, are the appends guaranteed to be executed in order?

UPDATE: Added clarification that this is the only code acting on the file.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, your appends will occur in order and unless another process is writing to the target file, won't overwrite existing data.

Node is single threaded (from the perspective of a running application) and queues up file writes internally, so if you write `1` `2` and `3` to a file, the file will contain `123`.

Node does launch new threads to handle IO but this is a feature of the runtime and is hidden from developers.

*UPDATE*

On first reading, I missed your requirement that your appends occur in multiple calls where the callback is blank or non-functional.

This changes things immensely.

If you use an async call, like `fs.appendFile()`, you must provide a callback which must check for errors. If you stack async calls without waiting for their callbacks to conclude, *there is no guarantee your writes will occur in order or won't overwrite previous data.*

Bottom Line: **Do not use async functions without proper callbacks that always check for errors.**

To do otherwise breaks the whole idea of Node's event driven model.

The way I usually explain this is to consider that, in an async call, *you cannot predict when the callback will be triggered* due to numerous factors including cpu and IO load.

If you cannot know when a callback is triggered, you cannot predict multiple calls will run in sequence.

*UPDATE 2*

To be clear, you cannot call an async function without providing a callback and be guaranteed of *any* expected behavior.

Think about it in terms of events:

`fs.appendFile()` adds an event handler to an IO thread and sends an event containing its arguments to an IO thread.

Once the operation completes, this event handler is fired which is either your callback or will trigger your callback.

Without waiting for the operation to complete, you cannot be guaranteed it has succeeded or has done what you expect.

Comment: I appreciate the concern about callback hygiene and merely elided them for the purposes of exposition. My question specifically asks about the case where there are no errors.

Comment: Also, I'm hoping to learn what the _intentional guarantees_ are about the system, as opposed to the mere happenstance of its current implementation.

Comment: You cannot ignore callbacks to async functions and assume they will operate in any order. This is what callbacks are for, to guarantee synchronous behavior using asynchronous functions. This is not "hygiene", it is a requirement of event-driven programming.

Comment: As far as guarantees go, if you misuse the tool you cannot be guaranteed it will perform as expected.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I'd love to know what I've misunderstood and am happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146296/discussion-between-rob-raisch-and-danfuzz).